# MYSQL UNION producing unexpected results and missing columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to merge results from two different tables, the only thing they have in common is a date field called date_mod

The query below only shows the two columns from the first select statement. The profile_id column isn't shown.

Any help on how to tweak it so I can get the 5 most recent results from both tables combined based on the order the date_mod field would be great.

```
SELECT resume_id,  date_mod FROM resumes  ORDER BY date_mod 
UNION ALL 
SELECT profile_id, date_mod FROM profiles ORDER BY date_mod LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The profile_id is shown, but a column has only one label - the label from the first select.

```
SELECT resume_id as id,  date_mod as date, 'resume' as type FROM resumes
UNION ALL 
SELECT profile_id, date_mod, 'profile' FROM profiles 
ORDER BY date 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT resume_id as `ID`,  date_mod
    FROM resumes
         UNION
    SELECT profile_id as `ID`, date_mod
    FROM profiles) iResult 
ORDER BY iResult.date_mod
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: `UNION` would trigger an unnecessary implicit sort, so `UNION ALL` would be more preferable. Otherwise this is just what I was about to post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the limit 5 is causing the issue you should probably wrap the query i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT resume_id,date_mod FROM resumes ORDER BY date_mod UNION ALL SELECT profile_id, date_mod FROM profiles ORDER BY date_mod) LIMIT 5
```

This should provide what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got an error on that because of ORDER BY, so I tried a simplified: SELECT * FROM (SELECT resume_id,date_mod FROM resumes UNION ALL SELECT profile_id, date_mod FROM profiles). However this gave me an 'every table requires an alias' error, going to play with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply order on merge base :

```
(SELECT resume_id,  date_mod FROM resumes 
UNION ALL 
SELECT profile_id, date_mod FROM profiles ) ORDER BY date_mod LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing a UNION, the columns must be of the same "alias" column result and data type to qualify.  If you want the top 5, you should actually apply a limit to BOTH sets to get at MOST 5 from both sides.  THEN apply an OVERALL Limit 5 so you are not pre-returning ALL records from both individual files

```
select 
      Source,
      SrcID,
      Date_Mod
   from
      ( SELECT 
              "R" as Source,
              resume_id as SrcID,
              date_mod 
           FROM 
              resumes
           ORDER BY 
              date_mod 
           LIMIT 5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
              "P" as Source,
              profile_id as SrcID,
              date_mod
           FROM 
              profiles 
           ORDER BY 
              date_mod 
           LIMIT 5 ) PreQuery
   order by
      Date_Mod
   LIMIT 5
```